# Curl Catch Redirect Url parameters - Oauth 2.0 Authorisation PHP script for API request (VK for example)

Tags: php, curl, oauth, redirect, vk

I have a problem with a two step authorization with Oauth in PHP.

The first request like:

$AUTHORIZE_URL ='https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=myID&scope=MyWall&redirect_uri=https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html&response_type=code';

This request is making a redirection to https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html with "#code=Anumber" parameter.

After that I have a second request which need this code.

I use Curl to make those requests and parse the Json result of the second one but how can I get the paramters of the redirect url in curl.

I tried to parse the header of the answer but I found no location.

EDIT:

Example code of my request:

```
curl_setopt_array($ch = curl_init(), array(
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => '',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => false,
    CURLINFO_REDIRECT_URL => true,
    CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => $url 
));
curl_exec($ch);
$info=curl_getinfo($ch);
prin_r($info);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Can you post the code where you make the curl request?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the problem is that you are not logged in, if you are logged in the OAuth authentication redirects you to the blank page with your code, but if you are not, there is NO REDIRECT and it shows you a html page with login.

So, in order to get that code you have to login, you can login using your browser and then get the cookies from your browser and use them in your code. This option is good if you only want that code for testing.

The second options is more complex you have to do the login programmatically, that implies more than one curl, saving cookies and sending them to the next request. I made an example for this OAuth authentication in particular that at least works for me. Is quite ugly but is ok as proof of concept.

```
<?php
$email = "myemailorphone";
$pass = "mypassword";
$id = "myID";
//this url returns a login page
$url= "https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?".http_build_query(["client_id"=>$id,"scope"=>"MyWall","redirect_uri"=>"https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html","response_type"=>"code"]);

$b64url = str_replace("==","--",base64_encode($url)); //different base64 code, just to have all parameters
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
//curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_NOBODY,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.85 Safari/537.36");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$cookieString = "";
if(strpos($result,"log in")) {

    //get all the cookies
    preg_match_all('/^Set-Cookie:\s*([^;]*)/mi', $result, $matches);
    $cookies = array();
    foreach($matches[1] as $item) {
        parse_str($item, $cookie);
        $cookies = array_merge($cookies, $cookie);
    }
    $cookieString = "";
    foreach($cookies as $key=>$val){
        $cookieString .= $key."=".$val.";";
    }
    //CREATE LOGIN POST
    $ip_h = explode("name=\"ip_h\" value=\"",$result);
    $ip_h = substr($ip_h[1],0,18); // some hidden fields on that page, maybe important
    $lg_h = explode("name=\"lg_h\" value=\"",$result);
    $lg_h = substr($lg_h[1],0,18); // some hidden fields on that page, maybe important
    $fields = [
                    "origin"=>"https://oauth.vk.com",
                    "to"=>$b64url, // this is where it redirects after login, not used in the php code but, just for the request
                    "email"=>$email,//phone or email of user
                    "expire"=>0,
                    "pass"=>$pass, //your password
                    "ip_h"=>$ip_h,
                    "lg_h"=>$lg_h
              ];

    $post = http_build_query($fields);

    $login_url = "https://login.vk.com/?act=login&soft=1";

    $ch = curl_init($login_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Cookie: '.$cookieString));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.85 Safari/537.36");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    //get the new cookies
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    preg_match_all('/^Set-Cookie:\s*([^;]*)/mi', $result, $matches);
    $login_cookies = array();
    foreach($matches[1] as $item) {
        parse_str($item, $cookie);
        $login_cookies = array_merge($login_cookies, $cookie);
    }
    foreach($login_cookies as $key=>$val){
        $cookieString .= $key."=".$val.";";
    }
    //get next location redirect
    preg_match_all('/^Location:\s*(.*)/mi', $result, $matches);
    $first_redirect = str_replace("\"","_",$matches[1][0]);
    $first_redirect = filter_var($first_redirect,FILTER_SANITIZE_URL); //sanitize url, because it returns unwanted chars

    //use the second location redirect 
    $ch = curl_init($first_redirect);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.85 Safari/537.36");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Cookie: '.$cookieString,"accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8"));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);


    //last location forward
    preg_match_all('/^Location:\s*(.*)/mi', $result, $matches);
    $second_redirect = str_replace("\"","_",$matches[1][0]);
    $second_redirect = filter_var($second_redirect,FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);


    $ch = curl_init($second_redirect);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.85 Safari/537.36");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Cookie: '.$cookieString,"accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8"));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

    preg_match_all('/^Location:\s*(.*)/mi', $result, $matches);
    $blank = str_replace("\"","_",$matches[1][0]);
    $blank = filter_var($blank,FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);


    echo "Blank url: ".$blank;

}


 ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Payn3. It works, I can parse the result and use the Code. I don't understand every step in your script put I will. Thank you.